# Parse DateTime when given as a Number/Double

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, time, dbf

I am working with some date times from a piece of weather hardware which logs to a .dbf file. I can pull this up from the ruby script/web server I am using, but I get numbers such as

41836.532638889

I am unsure how the date time is represented so having a hard time of knowing how to parse it. I would preferably like to parse it in Ruby, so code would be a plus, but I could figure out how to do it if I knew how it was represented.

Comment: I'm curious what that number means, but it has nothing to do with Ruby.  I'd be inclined to contact the manufacture of the hardware to get the relevant docs.

Comment: How are you getting the `41836.532638889` value out of the dbf file? dbf datetime fields are not stored as floats.

Comment: I am using a dbf parsing gem. When I open the file in LibreOffice (the instructions say dbf is excel readable, but seeing as I am on linux, libreoffice is second best option), it has that time format as well. Probably worth adding that the earliest recording dates back no more than a year, possibly less and is at 30,000 or so. My best guess is X days/hours/etc after Y date, just don't know what X and Y are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is an OLE Automation formatted date which is common in Excel. As Google says it is

`An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component     is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24.`

The corresponding Ruby code is

```
def self.convert_time(t)
  Time.at((t - 25569) * 86400).utc
end
```

The subtraction shifts the time to the day unix time starts (1 January 1970). Unix time is in seconds so converting days to seconds: 24*60*60=86400. Converting to utc time for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try Time.at(your_number/double). You can then format it as required.

```
Time.at(41836.532638889)
=> 1970-01-01 12:37:16 +0100
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that gives the correct time (which is sometime today July 16, 2014). 

The data goes a few months back and reaches to a number in the 30,000s. So I don't think its seconds from the start of its own time either (and the original software that reads it parses the time correctly) and its not seconds from epoch (which is what Time.at does).

Answer (score 0):

41836 - number of days passed from 12/31/1899 (zero-date), 532638889 - number of seconds passed from the midnight of the date mentioned.